# What to call a non-edge in a network?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Suppose I have a network with nodes and some edges between the nodes. If node $x$ and node $y$ have an edge, then we say that $(x,y)$ corresponds to the edge between $x$ and $y$. Now suppose that $x$ and $y$ do not have an edge between them, what is the proper terminology to call a possible link between $x$ and $y$? Do we call it **the dyad** $(x,y)$?

I have a presentation about graphs, so I'm thinking about my words. So is it correct to say "if node $x$ and node $y$ do not have a link between each other, then $(x,y)$ is the dyad between node $x$ and node $y$". I'm really having a bad time finding the correct terminology to describe the case where there is no edge! So I want to talk about a link between two nodes, but that link does not exist yet, so I want to say that we have a dyad and then this dyads becomes an edge. How can I say that correctly please?

Comment: Why not just "pair"?

Comment: Yes, some pairs $(x,y)$ are edges and some are not. What about this terminology?

Comment: Pair of nonadjacent vertices

Comment: @HenningMakholm because a pair is still not descriptive for the fact that the dyad $(x,y)$ could become a link. A pair does not become a link. I want a terminology that describes a 'thing' that could become a link. So far 'dyad' is the closest thing I could find.

Comment: @JackTwain: Why not "potential edge", then?

Comment: @HenningMakholm because it is odd to say "the potential edge $(x,y)$ could become an edge".

Comment: @JackTwain: But you could say the potential edge $(x,y)$ becomes an actual one under such-and-such conditions.

Comment: @HenningMakholm still odd and confusing for the audience :(

Comment: @JackTwain: Not half as odd and confusing as using words like "dyad", which frankly just sounds like "I wanted to say pair but forgot what the word was".

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with just saying "non-edge"?